# dlopen failed :trying to develop native camera app

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-camera

**ERROR:**

```
03-18 15:24:46.441: E/art(1762): dlopen("/data/app/com.nvidia.NativeCamera-1/lib/arm/libnative_camera2.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android11BufferQueueC1ERKNS_2spINS_19IGraphicBufferAllocEEE" referenced by "libnative_camera2.so"...
```

**Application.mk**

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8


APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a



APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_PLATFORM := android-19

APP_CFLAGS = -gdwarf-2 -DANDROID -DUSE_REGAL
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(NV_MODULE_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeCamera
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeCamera.cpp ImageSave.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += nvappbase nvui nvassetloader nvglutils nveglutil nvgamepad external_regal
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -lEGL -landroid
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += native_camera2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

    $(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/external)
    $(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../)

    $(call import-module,nvapp)
    $(call import-module,native_camera2);
```

Note: I have tried changing to `gnustl_shared`.It Does not work.I am trying to develop a native android camera app, but I have runtime error. `$(NV_MODULE_PATH)` refers to jni folder which contains external\nvapp. 2 folders before i have native_camera2. SO there are no location errors nor compilation error. Just linking error libnative_camera2.so in runtime. This native_camera2 is a prebuilt library by nvidia which i am trying to use.